# Custom Route Component Never Matches on exact path="/"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

This is a bit of a complicated problem, so I'll keep it as brief as possible.

**Symptoms**

I have a PrivateRoute component built around the `react-router-dom` Router component. Essentially, the Route is supplied a list of `allowedRoles` and a boolean value called `allBut`. If `allBut == true`, the user can view the route if they possess any user roles *not* included in `allowedRoles`. If it's `false`, they can view it if they have any roles that *are* included in `allowedRoles`. If the user is authorized, the route will render its children, else it will render a `React.ReactNode` supplied through its `unauthorizedRedirect` prop. It works great, except for one infuriating caveat.

Running the following Jest/React Testing Library test:

```js
  const SUCCESS_MESSAGE = "Success; you're authorized!";
  const LOGIN_MESSAGE = "You weren't logged in, so we redirected you!";
  const RENDER_ON_AUTH = () => <div>{SUCCESS_MESSAGE}</div>;
  const RENDER_ON_LOGIN = () => <div>{LOGIN_MESSAGE}</div>;
  test('PrivateRoute renders its children when user holds a role other than the roles listed in allowedRoles when allBut == true', () => {
    const testContext = cloneDeep(CUSTOM_CONTEXT);
    testContext.devSettings.userOverride.userRoles = [DefaultRoles.Authenticated];
    render(
      <ProvideAuth customContext={testContext}>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute
              exact
              path="/"
              allowedRoles={[DefaultRoles.Anonymous]}
              allBut={true}
              unauthorizedRedirect={<Redirect to="/login" />}
            >
              <RENDER_ON_AUTH />
            </PrivateRoute>
            <Route path="/login">
              <RENDER_ON_LOGIN />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </ProvideAuth>
    );
    const hopefullySuccessDiv = screen.queryByText(SUCCESS_MESSAGE);
    expect(hopefullySuccessDiv).toBeInTheDocument();
    const hopefullyNotLoginDiv = screen.queryByText(LOGIN_MESSAGE);
    expect(hopefullyNotLoginDiv).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

results in:

```
expect(received).toBeInTheDocument()

    received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement.
    Received has value: null

      55 |     );
      56 |     const hopefullySuccessDiv = screen.queryByText(SUCCESS_MESSAGE);
    > 57 |     expect(hopefullySuccessDiv).toBeInTheDocument();
         |                                 ^
      58 |     const hopefullyNotLoginDiv = screen.queryByText(LOGIN_MESSAGE);
      59 |     expect(hopefullyNotLoginDiv).not.toBeInTheDocument();
      60 |   });
```

You're probably thinking at this point, "Well, the PrivateRoute is obviously broken. The authorization isn't working, and it's redirecting to '/login'".

Yeah, maybe, but...

The following test will pass with flying colors (as will any other test that results in an "authorized" status:

```js
  test('PrivateRoute renders its children when user holds a role other than the roles listed in allowedRoles when allBut == true', () => {
    const testContext = cloneDeep(CUSTOM_CONTEXT);
    testContext.devSettings.userOverride.userRoles = [DefaultRoles.Authenticated];
    render(
      <ProvideAuth customContext={testContext}>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Redirect exact from="/" to="/home" />
            <PrivateRoute
              exact
              path="/home"
              allowedRoles={[DefaultRoles.Anonymous]}
              allBut={true}
              unauthorizedRedirect={<Redirect to="/login" />}
            >
              <RENDER_ON_AUTH />
            </PrivateRoute>
            <Route path="/login">
              <RENDER_ON_LOGIN />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </ProvideAuth>
    );
    const hopefullySuccessDiv = screen.queryByText(SUCCESS_MESSAGE);
    expect(hopefullySuccessDiv).toBeInTheDocument();
    const hopefullyNotLoginDiv = screen.queryByText(LOGIN_MESSAGE);
    expect(hopefullyNotLoginDiv).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

See the difference?

There's a `Redirect` from/to. The redirect matches on "/" and redirects to "/home", at which point the PrivateRoute catches on and performs its logic. I've tested this every which way -- PrivateRoute works in every situation EXCEPT matching on `exact path="/"`.

Please, help. I'm pulling my hair out.

Here are some more implementation details:

```js
// src/components/routes/PrivateRoute.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuth, authorize } from '../../auth/auth';
import { PrivateRouteComponentProps } from './privateRouteTypes';

/**
 * Renders its children if the user is in one of the allowed roles,
 * else renders the unauthorizedRedirect ReactNode.
 */
const PrivateRoute = ({
  allowedRoles,
  unauthorizedRedirect,
  allBut,
  children,
  ...rest
}: PrivateRouteComponentProps & { unauthorizedRedirect: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const auth = useAuth();
  const isAuthorized = authorize(allowedRoles, auth.user, allBut);
  return <Route {...rest} render={() => (isAuthorized ? children : unauthorizedRedirect)} />;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

```js
// src/components/routes/privateRouteProps.ts
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

export interface PrivateComponentProps {
  allowedRoles: Roles;
  allBut?: boolean;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export type PrivateRouteComponentProps = {
  [key: string]: any;
} & PrivateComponentProps &
  Partial<RouteComponentProps>;

export type PrivateRouteComponent = (props: PrivateRouteComponentProps) => JSX.Element;
```